# how to draw image frame for camera view and overlapping the image frame on captured image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas, bitmapimage

I am new in android and working on the camera application. In this app I have one transparent image (Image Frame) in assets folder and I want to show this file as my camera view unlike the native camera view. I am getting the camera view screen with the Image Frame using imageview over surface but unable to merge them as output image file on sdcard. Please help

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            Drawable drbl=null;
            Bitmap topImage = null ;
            Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(ref_capturedBitmap.getWidth(), ref_capturedBitmap.getHeight(), ref_capturedBitmap.getConfig());
            Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(b);


            int width = ref_capturedBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = ref_capturedBitmap.getHeight();

            Log.v("CameraCaptureActivity","Width : "+width+" Height : "+height );
            if (frameStatus == 0)
                drbl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maske1r);
            else if (frameStatus == 1)
                drbl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maske2r);
            else if (frameStatus == 2)
                drbl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maske3r);

            drbl.setBounds(0, 0, height, width);
            Bitmap tpImg=((BitmapDrawable)drbl).getBitmap();
            topImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tpImg, width, height, true);

            comboImage.drawBitmap(ref_capturedBitmap,0f,0f,null);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(topImage, 0f, 0f, null);
                            return b;
```

Comment: Hello friends, after so much googling and code review I found the above best solution for my question.