# merge two images (one image is without face, second image is only face)

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, face-detection

I have a two image one image is containing body without face and one image contain with face only...

now i want to merge this two images.... the first image which contain only body without face is in that the face is transparent.....

so **how can i detect that transparent area and place face over there in transparent area**

i am combining two images with below code.. **but it is not proper way to place face over transparent area**

below is my code

```
 public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
    Bitmap cs = null;

    int width, height = 0;

    if (c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) {
        width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    } else {
        width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    }

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, 0f, null);

    return cs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the face area of the body image is transparent? I.e. the alpha value in some part of the body image is low?

Comment: If you do a connected component labeling on the body image, you should be able to find with the face should be, and the size of the face from the bounding box.

Comment: here's a link on combining bitmap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616777/how-to-merge-to-two-bitmap-one-over-another