# Improving file save performance in android

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap

I have 100 images on external memory which i do these two following tasks in a for loop .

1. Loading every item as a bitmap and merging it with another bitmap
2. Saving result in as a new file in memory

And for 100 images it takes too much time . Merging bitmaps is quit fast and OK but saving the result in file takes too much time . Is there anyway to boost this issue ? Keeping the bitmaps in memory and batch save files can cause OutOfMemoryException .

This is how i merge bitmaps :
[how to merge to two bitmap one over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616777/how-to-merge-to-two-bitmap-one-over-another)

This is how i save the bitmap to file :

```
       File imageFileFolder = new File(Statics.TEMP_PATH);
    imageFileFolder.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    File imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, imageName);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that all of these are in a AsyncTask block .

Comment: you could try whether adding a buffer, i.e. `out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imageFileName), 8 * 1024);` (try larger size as well) has any measurable effect.

Comment: What is too much time? Please tell how many seconds. Also tell file sizes. Use the cores of the cpu and use threads. One thread for every core. Or two.

Comment: @greenapps saving file is an expensive task . if you have any solution please tell me and i will tell you the difference .  Because the data set is not very important .

Comment: @zapl ok i will check

Comment: You did not give the info i asked for. And i told you already a solution.

Comment: according to this : stackoverflow.com/questions/8712957/… Using BufferedOutputStream makes it worst . Because file sizes are about 150kb each @zapl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came with the solution to save Bitmap as jpeg. Saving a 250k png bitmap took almost 500 milliseconds . The same bitmap in jpeg format took about 50 milliseconds. Although the qualities wont be the same but it looks like it is a tradeoff between quality and performance.